# Using MySQL Cast to find Wordpress posts with a custom field content equivalent to Price

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, casting

I am using custom fields in Wordpress to contain an 'RRP' currency value.  This field is text based, but I want to be able to run queries where I can bring out posts which have an RRP in a specific range.

I've been looking into the MySQL CAST function and this seems to be the right thing, but I can't seem to get it working.  Everything I use seems to just become 0.00.  Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
SELECT wpostmeta.meta_value, CAST( 'wpostmeta.meta_value' AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) , wposts . *
FROM tc_posts wposts, tc_postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'rrp'
AND CAST( 'wpostmeta.meta_value' AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) < 9.99
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: Can you show some example values of `meta_value`?

Comment: you might also want to accept answers for your previous questions in order to motivate people to give you a good answer on this one ;)

Comment: @Pekka Meta value holds loads of different types of data. It is a LONGTEXT field and holds what appear to be serialised PHP objects (or arrays), as well as text and numeric data. 

I have two rows that should match the 'meta_key' constraint and they have the values of 1999.99 and 99.99.

Comment: okay. Then the first thing to do is to make a basic query to see whether the conversion works at all: `SELECT wpostmeta.meta_value, CAST( 'wpostmeta.meta_value' AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) , wposts.* FROM tc_posts wposts, tc_postmeta wpostmeta` (maybe limit it to the two rows that match the constraint). If this results in `0` then something is wrong with the CAST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see your problem here. `'wpostmeta.meta_value'` will give you 0 when casted, you should get rid of those quotes, since it's the value you want to cast from, not the name of the field:

```
SELECT wpostmeta.meta_value, CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), wposts.*
FROM tc_posts wposts, tc_postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'rrp'
AND CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) < 9.99
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

Cheers.

Comment: Got it working now using the pointer about the quotes. Thanks for the input everyone.

SELECT CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS cast_price
FROM wpostmeta
WHERE wpostmeta.key_value='rrp'
AND
CAST(wpostmeta.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) > 109.99